# How to set exceptions inside "yield" for Scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

Good day,

I'm trying to scrape GitHub using Scrapy. It works for the most part, but some pages load "contributors" after the page itself is done loading.
When Scrapy encounters such a page it throws the following error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'` and discards everything else from that URL.

Is there a way to make an exception inside "yield" so Scrapy puts "None" into the resulting .CSV instead of throwing all the data away?

Here's the relevant code:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('Repositories'), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@rel="next"]'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('github'), restrict_xpaths=('//h3/a[@class="v-align-middle"]')), callback='parse_project'),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('commits/master'), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@class="commits"]/a')), follow=True, callback='parse_commits_page'),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=('\+174'), restrict_xpaths=('//a[contains(text(), "Older")]')), follow=True, callback='parse_commits_page')
]

# Parse the main page of the project
def parse_project(self, response):
    yield {
        'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
        'name': response.xpath('//strong[@itemprop="name"]/a/text()').extract(),
        'tags': [x.strip() for x in response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "topic-tag")]/text()').extract()],
        'about': response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="about"]/text()').extract_first().strip(),
        'lang_name': response.xpath('//span[@class = "lang"]/text()').extract(),
        'lang_perc' : response.xpath('//span[@class = "percent"]/text()').extract(),
        'stars': response.xpath('//a[contains(@aria-label, "starred")]/text()').extract_first().strip(),
        'forks': response.xpath('//a[contains(@aria-label, "forked")]/text()').extract_first().strip(),
        'commits': response.xpath('//a[contains(., "commits")]/span/text()').extract_first().strip(),
        'contributors': response.xpath('//a[contains(., "contributor")]/span/text()').extract_first().strip(),
        'last_commits': None
    }
```

In particular,`'contributors': response.xpath('//a[contains(., "contributor")]/span/text()').extract_first().strip(),` is the part that gives me trouble and where I want the exception.

P.S. I've also tried to make it wait for the page using "scrapy-splash"

```
def pre_parse_project(self, response):
    yield scrapy_splash.SplashRequest(response.url, self.parse_project,
        args={
            'wait': 4,
        }
    )
```

but the problem persisted, so I would like to at least get all the data I can and populate the number of contributors using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it like this:

```
>>> test = None
>>> test.strip() if test is not None else "fallback"
'fallback'
```

In your code this would look like:

```
def parse_project(self, response):
    yield {
        'author': response.xpath('//a[@rel="author"]/text()').extract(),
        'name': response.xpath('//strong[@itemprop="name"]/a/text()').extract(),
        'tags': [x.strip() for x in response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "topic-tag")]/text()').extract()],
        'about': response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="about"]/text()').extract_first().strip(),
        'lang_name': response.xpath('//span[@class = "lang"]/text()').extract(),
        'lang_perc' : response.xpath('//span[@class = "percent"]/text()').extract(),
        'stars': response.xpath('//a[contains(@aria-label, "starred")]/text()').extract_first().strip(),
        'forks': response.xpath('//a[contains(@aria-label, "forked")]/text()').extract_first().strip(),
        'commits': response.xpath('//a[contains(., "commits")]/span/text()').extract_first().strip(),
        'contributors': response.xpath('//a[contains(., "contributor")]/span/text()').extract_first().strip() if response.xpath('//a[contains(., "contributor")]/span/text()').extract_first() is not None else None,
        'last_commits': None
    }
```

Comment: Can you double-check, please? I might have gotten lucky. When I check [this page](https://github.com/martanne/vis-test) that has no "about" section, I still get the error with proposed method: 

`>>> response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="about"]/text()').extract_first().strip() if response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="about"]/text()').extract_first().strip() is not None else None`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`    File "<console>", line 1, in <module> `
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' `

Comment: My bad, sorry. There should be no `.strip()`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
yield {
    'contributors': response.xpath(selector)\
                            .extract_first()\
                            .strip(),
}
```

You can use the `default` parameter (so that it will not return None):

```
yield {
    'contributors': response.xpath(selector)\
                            .extract_first(default='')\
                            .strip(),
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
That looks way more elegant.